# Animated gif as user picture in OS X?

Tags: macos, user-account, system-settings, ui

How can I set an animated gif as user picture in OS X? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible. When you specify an account picture, macOS will automatically convert the image file to `.tiff` file format and save it in the cache. Unlike `.gif`, `.tiff` is a single-image file format, so once your `.gif` file is converted, the animation will be lost.